# gremlin: sack modification in filter has no effect

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Im filtering some vertices via their properties and map them with a `project()` step. In the result I want all vertices which have at least one property that matches my filter, and the amount of properties that matched. I already tried `as()` with `select()`  - which got me a null value. The `aggregate()`-step returned an array that contained all matching property amounts of all traversers. So now I am trying `sack()` but this also gets me 'null'

This is my query in short form:

```
   g.V(someId)
       .project("child_label","other_child_label")
       .by(
          __.out()
          .hasLabel("child_label")
          .filter(
                  __.properties()
                  .filter(__.key().is(Text.contains("foo")))
                  .filter(__.value().is(Text.contains("bar")))
                  .fold()
                  .sack(assign).by(__.count())
                  .count()
                  .is(P.gt(0L))
          )
          .project("name","foundProps")
          .by("name")
          .by(__.sack())
          .fold()
       )
     //exactly the same just with one more out-step
     .by(
          __.out()
          .out()
          .hasLabel("child_label")
          .filter(
                  __.properties()
                  .filter(__.key().is(Text.contains("foo")))
                  .filter(__.value().is(Text.contains("bar")))
                  .fold()
                  .sack(assign).by(__.count())
                  .count()
                  .is(P.gt(0L))
          )
          .project("name","foundProps")
          .by("name")
          .by(__.sack())
          .fold()
       )
   )
```

The result for `"foundProps"` is for all found vertices 0. Why?
I already verified that `count()` returns the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is going on in this case.

Inside the `filter` step, it's going to essentially spawn an anonymous traversal to carry out the filtering steps, but, that traversal never exits the filter step, so any `sack` modifications done within it will be lost also. This is similar to why using `sack` inside a `sideEffect` step does not work.

This is different to, say, a `union` step (which is a kind of branch) where the traversals spawned inside the step may exit it and their `sack` (if any) will be preserved.